# Linear optimization with rotation matrix constraint

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, rotations, lagrange-multiplier, constraint-programming

I have a linear cost function $f(r_{11},r_{12},...r_{33}, t_1, t_2, t_3)$ in terms of the elements of a 4x4 matrix $RT$. It is a rotation cum translation matrix and so the search should obey the equality constraint for $r_{11}$ to $r_{33}$ being elements of a rotation matrix $R$ which is  $R^T * R = I$. 
\begin{equation}
RT =
\begin{pmatrix}
r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} & t_1 \\
r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23} & t_2 \\
r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} & t_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

What is the best optimization method to solve this problem? My cost function is not of the form $f(R)$ and hence I think I cannot use the suggestion given in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207514/nonlinear-optimization-with-rotation-matrix-constraint). I found people using Lagrange Multipliers approach for constrained optimization. In that case $R^T * R = I$  will generate 9 constraints, equating to each element of $I$. Is that right?

Comment: It is not a constraint which is so easy to express linearly.

Comment: Maybe you can instead optimize for $T$ and $C$ in $TCT^{-1} = R$. You know what $C$ is supposed to look like.

Comment: Sorry, I did not follow your suggestion. Do you want me to split $R$ into $T$ and $C$ ? So how do I split $R$? My cost function is of the form $c_{1}r_{11}+c_{2}r_{12}+...+c_{9}r_{33}+c_{10}t_{1}+c_{11}t_{2}+c_{12}t_{3}=constant$. Are you suggesting me to change the cost function ?

Comment: You can keep the cost function, but add two matrices $C$ and $T$ for regularization to help push your $R$ into a subspace that is allowed.